# C, With the same memory addresses but different value

Tags: c, pointers

Interestingly, I have pointers with the same memory addresses but they gives me different values.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char charactor = 55;
    int number = 1234;

    int *pointer1;
    char *pointer2;

    pointer1 = &number;
    pointer2 = (char *)pointer1;

    printf("pointer1: %p, %d\n", pointer1, *pointer1);
    printf("pointer2: %p, %d\n", pointer2, (int)*pointer2);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling these lines of code, I got:

```
pointer1: 0x7ffee401b8b4, 1234
pointer2: 0x7ffee401b8b4, -46
```

Is this related to the way pointers are expressed, such as octal decimal or something?

Comment: You're aware that in the second printf you got a `char`, aka 8 bits signed integer, value 0xd2, and print it as sign extended integer=-46? The whole integer is 0x04d2=1234.

Answer (score 2):

Signed decimal numbers are not good for such a tests as it very hard to guess what values are in the particular bytes (I program 35 years and I cant do it). In the hex number two digits represent one byte.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char charactor = 0x11;
    int number = 0x1234;

    int *pointer1;
    char *pointer2;

    pointer1 = &number;
    pointer2 = (char *)pointer1;

    printf("pointer1: %p, 0x%x\n", (void *)pointer1, *pointer1);
    printf("pointer2: %p, 0x%x\n", (void *)pointer2, (int)*pointer2);

    for(int index = 0; index < sizeof(number); index++)
    {
        printf("byte %d - 0x%02hhx\n", index, pointer2[index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/wRAjy8

The result -

```
pointer1: 0x7fffb3267654, 0x1234
pointer2: 0x7fffb3267654, 0x34
byte 0 - 0x34
byte 1 - 0x12
byte 2 - 0x00
byte 3 - 0x00
```

from the results you can learn about little endian. First is stored the least significant byte. The last is the most significant one.

As both pointers reference the same place in the memory - the `char *` gets one byte - the least significant one - which is clearly visible in this example.

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
 printf("pointer2: %p, %d\n", pointer2, (int)*pointer2);
```

probably does not do what you expect it to do. You should do

```
 printf("pointer2: %p, %d\n", pointer2, *(int *)pointer2);
```

to get the integer value stored at memory location pointed to by `pointer2`.

Comment: @P__J__ how is that?

Comment: 7.19.6.1     ------

Comment: @P__J__ which part? Mentioning a whole chapter is not helpful.

Comment: @SouravGhosh he  means `%p` wants a cast: `(void *)pointer2` instead of `pointer2`, quoting the standard is somewhat stupid in those cases.

Comment: @DavidRanieri thanks, in that case, I'm afraid a re-read of the spec is needed. a `char*` and `void *` has same alignment requirement and does not need a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers retain the type of the variable they're pointing at.

When you dereference pointer to an integer, the `sizeof(int)` bytes will be accessed. Dereferencing pointer to a character accesses `sizeof(char)` bytes in the memory.

Since you store 1234, or 0b10011010010, at the address `0x7fffb3267654`, the memory will look like as follows, assuming [little-endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

```
0x7fffb3267654: 11010010
0x7fffb3267658: 00000100
0x7fffb326765c: 00000000
0x7fffb3267660: 00000000
```

Little-endianness is the dominant way of ordering bytes in memory on CPU architectures, including the [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) family of processors, and explains the behavior you're describing.

Reading one byte from the address `0x7fffb3267654` will return `11010010`. If you interpret this byte as a signed char (which seems to be the way your compiler handles `char`), you'll get the decimal value of -46.

Comment: "the memory will look like this" -- please clarify that you are assuming a little-endian CPU architecture.

Comment: @zwol A very good point, I have updated the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This casting is wrong printf("pointer2: %p, %d\n", pointer2, (int)*pointer2);

what you are actually printing is the same address but with less bits instead of printing four bytes (int) you are still printing only 1 byte (char) but with sign is the same number but not considering the other bits from the int.

pointer1: 0x7ffee401b8b4, 1234
pointer2: 0x7ffee401b8b4, -46

‭pointer1:  0100 1101 0010‬   1234
‭pointer2:       1101 0010‬    -46

Comment: Rather than *just* pointing out what is wrong in the OPs code, a good answer should *also* offer a way to fix it.